# how can extract parameter from @QueryParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/categories")
    public Response getAllCategories(@QueryParam(value = "code") String country_code) {

        return userService.getAllCategories(country_code);
}
```

**my url:"/user/categories?code=+91"**

how can i extracting request parameters "+91" in RESTful web service.

Comment: There is nothing Spring related in your code, so why is it tagged as spring and spring-mvc?

Comment: Try removing the value in the parenthesis. As in `@QueryParam("code")`

Comment: @YoungMillie value="code" is completely equal to writing just "code".

Comment: You are consuming JSON in a GET request. Try with POST.

Answer (score 0):

`@QueryParam` is JAX-RS. If you want to use Spring, the appropriate annotation would be `@RequestParam`:

```
public Response getAllCategories(@RequestParam("code") String country_code) {
...
}
```

But of course, `@Path`, etc. are also not Spring, so perhaps you should ask yourself if you actually want to use Spring...